# How to resolve infection SMW-INJ-15328-cron.bkdr.perl-3 found by ImunifyAv

Tags: security, malware, cpanel, whm

I have a report of a malware infection from imunifyAv and this is all I'm given:

```
SHELL="/usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailshell"
*/9 * * * * perl /var/tmp/CpUOSh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Reason: SMW-INJ-15328-cron.bkdr.perl-3

ChatGPT tells me I need to remove the line ***/9 * * * * perl /var/tmp/CpUOSh >/dev/null 2>&1** from the crontab file. I don't see that line in the crontab file.

This is on a dedicated server running Centos 7.9 with WHM and CPanel.

How do I rectify this infection?